# PHP Using Object to Retrieve DB data

Tags: php, oop, pdo

I am wondering if someone could help me. I am new to PHP OOP and would like some guidance with using objects.

I am making a login script and the functions I mention below are all from the class file.

```
Class USER{

public function userLogin($username,$password)
{   
    $statusY = "Y";

    $stmt  = $this->connection->prepare("SELECT * FROM tbl_users WHERE user_name=:userName  LIMIT 1");
    $stmt ->execute(array(":userName"=>$username));
    $row = $stmt ->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        if($stmt->rowCount() == 1)
        {

        $this->_user = $row; // Assign user details

        $_SESSION['userSession'] = $row['user_id'];

        }
}


public function getUser()
{
    return $this->_user;
}
```

Ok so I have the getUser() function and then assign $this->_user = $row so I can retrieve the user info from the database. Now I want to acheive a couple of things from this but not sure how to go about it.

How would I go about calling $row['user_id'] in another function within the same class?

So basically

```
public function test()
{
$user_id = $this->_user(user_id);
$username = $this->_user(username);
}
```

How would I do this correctly?

Also if I want to call the information in a page such as the User Homepage.

```
 $user_home = new USER();
 $userID = $user_home->getUser(user_id);

 echo $userID;
```

If anyone could give me some guidance as to how I can move forward with this I would greatly appreciate it. Thanks

Comment: Just declare _user as class  variable eg : public $_user;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start with a basic statement regarding method and class naming: I wouldn't repeat the class' topic over and over again (in the above case "user"), instead just remove it from the method name:

```
class User 
{
  private $info= array();
  private $authenticated= FALSE;

  public function login ($username, $password)
  {
    // do your stuff 
    ...
    // set in case that user name and password have been found
    $this->info= $row;
    $this->authenticated= TRUE;
  }

  public function isAuthenticated () 
  {
    return $this->authenticated;
  }

  /**
  * returns all info from a given user
  */
  public function get ()
  {
    return $this->info;
  }

  /**
  * returns a single field
  */
  public function getField ($fieldName) {
    if (isset($this->info[$fieldName]) {
      return $this->info[$fieldName];
    } else {
      return FALSE;
    }
  }
}
```

Use the `getField(FIELD)` method to return only a single element of the user's row and `get()` to return all values.

```
$user= new User();
$user->login ($username, $password);
if ($user->isAuthenticated()) {
  $home= $user->getField('home');
  print sprintf('%s\'s home is %s', $username, $home);
}
```

It's also advisable to create a class for the user database table (i.e. `class UserModel`) and another one handling user functions (i.e. `class UserAuth`) which uses the `UserModel` class. This makes exchanging the underlying authentication source more easy.

Comment: Thank you very much for your example, you have put it in prespective for me. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

```
Class USER
 {
   public $_user;

   public function userLogin($username,$password)
   {   
      $statusY = "Y";

    $stmt  = $this->connection->prepare("SELECT * FROM tbl_users WHERE user_name=:userName  LIMIT 1");
$stmt ->execute(array(":userName"=>$username));
$row = $stmt ->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    if($stmt->rowCount() == 1)
    {

    $this->_user = $row; // Assign user details

    $_SESSION['userSession'] = $row['user_id'];

    }
 }


public function getUser()
 {
return $this->_user;
}
 }
```